# Tappable visualization of a bar graph?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mobile

How can we make a bar of a bar graph look like it's tappable and will lead the user to someplace?

For example, in the below [image: sample bar graph]

if I want to make it intuitive to the user that clicking on the pink bar will take him to the details of firefox usage, how can I make it look clickable?

Comment: I think you might get a better answer on UX - this seems a bit more of a usability issue than a design issue.

Comment: "Intuitive" means that the function is common enough for users to expect it. Interactive bar charts are not common, so instead of trying to make it "intuitive", why not just tell the user? For instance, you could show a brief tour of the features before the user is allowed to interact with the chart. Or you could just have a text below the chart; "Tap on any bar to view detailed information"